# Create a macro like Q_PROPERTY and extract __VA_ARGS__

Tags: c++, qt, macros

How QT Q_PROPERTY macro work?

Q_PROPERTY:

```
    Q_PROPERTY(QString title READ title WRITE setTitle NOTIFY titleChanged)
```

I need to create a macro similar to Q_PROPERTY. my objective is to storage in vector the attribute of classes

for example i have a Person class

```
Person {

private:

std::string name;
std::string lastname;

public: 

std::string name();
void set_name(std::string name);

}
```

i want to do some like Q_PROPERTY in my class to storage the fields in vector how is called the getter, setter, and the type and name of the attribute

for example receive from macro this data:

TYPE
NAME
READ
WRITE

if i have a macro:

```
#define PROPERTY(...)

PROPERTY(std::string name READ name WRITE set_name)
PROPERTY(std::string email READ email WRITE set_email)
```

how i can extract the elements from **VA_ARGS** for example to do this:

```
__VA_ARGS__['TYPE'] this should write std::string
__VA_ARGS__['NAME'] this should write name
__VA_ARGS__['READ'] this should write name
__VA_ARGS__['WRITE']this should write set_name
```

with this data i want to write a structure to save it in a vector

and have all the class mapped to emulate a some reflection.

Comment: `__VA_ARGS__` simply forwards all the arguments captured to wherever it is used in the variadic macro. So: `#define M(...) f(__VA_ARGS__)` means that `M(foo, bar)` will expand to `f(foo, bar)`.

Answer (score 1):

Quick answer is "you can't" because `Q_PROPERTY` is not "just" a macro. If you follow it in the Qt code it eventually evaluates to nothing.  Why?  It is used by the Qt MOC pre-processor to build meta data about the class. If you look in your build tree, you'll see the generated .moc files. These are then compiled along with your class code.

So in other words to get the same functionality you'd need a pre-processor like MOC. I've wanted to do the same thing before. I couldn't really figure out a way w/out generating actual dynamic C++ code (like MOC does). Variadics are nice but there's definitely limits to what macros can do.